# Insert,Update data in datagridview C# from multiple tables

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview, inner-join, ssms

Guys i need help regarding my situation below:

I didn't find any solution,the problem is i want to insert,update data in C# using  a datagridview i will apreaciate if someone can give me an example how to do it.I  found some example where only 1 table was selected from the database.I use a select with inner join from 2 datables,the fact is that i was able to display the information but i don't know how to update,insert datagridview column,and update the tables from database.

Comment: Update each table individually. I'm not aware of a join update.

Comment: I'm not agree with you alternative,i need a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it, but you need to use some custom T/SQL. You can find a tutorial here

[Updating the TableAdapter to Use JOINs](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/data-access/advanced-data-access-scenarios/updating-the-tableadapter-to-use-joins-cs)

Comment: Thank you for your help.